# Use constant as Function attributes

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.3

I've a question about function declaration. I would like have something like:

```
password_hash('er', PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

When I create a function, I would like declare some possibilities like:

- PASSWORD_DEFAULT = 1
- PASSWORD_BCRYPT = 2
- PASSWORD_ARGON2I = 3
- PASSWORD_ARGON2ID = 4

Then, when the user use the function he just set the value of the constant or the constant.

Actually I do:

```
$instanceOfMyClass->myFunction('er', MyClass::A_CONSTANT);
```

It done the job, but I'm forced to write the class name before use the constant name. Then  if I do thaht I've access to all the constant of the class.

I think, I talk about something like constants at the function level.

Thanks a lot :-)

PS: Is there a way to do a DeclarationType like int|object|string for a function attribute ? Actually I don't type hint in this case, and for object, I need to specify a class or an Interface, sometimes, I accept many object to call the __toString() magic class, then I accept all objects.

Comment: So your question is about autocomplete in an IDE?  If so, what IDE?

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: mmm sorry, I've not explained it well. I would like create custom functions, and permit user to fill some arguments with constants like PASSWORD_DEFAULT, but just it (no function name with double :). Then in the function I retrieve the value of this constant. It's done by PHP with password_hash for example, you just write PASSWORD_DEFAULT and internaly it give an integer 0 in the function. By doing thaht, in PhpSorm for example, when you use the function it list the available constants for this argument.

Comment: Could you clarify what you don't like about the existing line? The `$instance->method(Class::CONST)` style seems correct and is widely used. As for the PS, unfortunately, union types like `int|object` did not make it into the language (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types). You can use a PHPdoc comment, which will be picked up by the IDE at least, though not enforced by PHP.

Comment: @ChristophBurschka By doing that, when you use the function you don't have help for retrieve specific constant (all class consant are not available for this function). When you use native PHP function, you just have possibilities to use available constant and the IDE have the capatibilities to find them (and it list it to you automatically when you start to fill the corresponding argument)? Thanks for your answer about Type hint :-)

Comment: This seems more like an IDE question than PHP... the IDE hints for "native" functions are hard-coded, and you can't recreate that with your own functions or methods, regardless of whether they're in a class. There was some discussion on letting PHPdoc comments hint a list of enumerated values/constants as arguments, but it didn't get anywhere. (https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/557)

Comment: But whithout IDE, if you use the function `password_hash('er', PASSWORD_ARGON2I);` or `password_hash('er', 1);` both work. And you don't write: `password_hash('er', password_hash::PASSWORD_ARGON2I);` if you would like to use the constant :( I think it's not possible but, I prefer ask it

Comment: You got the answer.  You use define().  It seems like you're being stubborn.  Define supports the exact example you started with in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your issue

> constants like PASSWORD_DEFAULT, but just it (no function name with double :).

but my guess is, you are looking for [`define()`](https://php.net/define).

I suggest you to utilize OOP as much as possible and so like others said, use class constants. But if you want global constants for whatever reason, it goes like this:

```
define('DIRECTION_FORWARD', 0);
define('DIRECTION_LEFT', 1);
define('DIRECTION_RIGHT', 2);

function goInDirection($direction = DIRECTION_FORWARD)
{
    // ....
}
```

Instead of just sequential numbers as values, you can use bitmasks, which work with bitwise operators and the power of 2.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: I've re-write a little my question. I don't really know how to ask it :/ I think it's not a possible thing...

Comment: This is literally the answer to the question, given the examples provided.  I don't know who downvoted it --- but I have a suspicion.

Comment: @gview Not me. I've try it and it work :-) Thanks a lot. Finally I have a better understanding. I've thinked we can define a constant for just a method, but it appear that the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is available everywhere. Then it's exactly the answer. And then I prefer continue lkike before with class constant.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it.

the defined constants can not be modified, but they can be analyzed and verified if a condition is met; although this one is doing all that; since it would be double work for something immutable / immutable

```
<?php
class Main{
    const CONSTANT = 'value constant';
    function ouputConts() {
        echo  var_dump(self::CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

in your case; that I can keep in a constant:

```
<?php
class Main{
    const CONSTANT1 = 1; //integer
    const CONSTANT2 = 0.1345; //float
    const CONSTANT3 = 'text'; //string
    const CONSTANT4 = array(1,2,3,4,5,10,20); //array
    const CONSTANT5 = true; //bollean
    function ouputConts() {
        echo var_dump(self::CONSTANT1);
        echo var_dump(self::CONSTANT2);
        echo var_dump(self::CONSTANT3);
        echo var_dump(self::CONSTANT4);
        echo var_dump(self::CONSTANT5);
    }
}
```

because in php an object or any type of object is considered mutable; you can not declare constants of type objects.

Documentation: 
https://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

So your other question is whether you can pass a constant as a property of a function:

Yes, but you should have some considerations:

If you are in the same class it is not necessary you can use the value in any function of the same class, without needing to pass it is Global for the class / Scope:

```
class Main{
    const CONSTANT = 'value constant';
    function function1() {
        $this->function2();
    }
    function function2() {
        $this->function3();
    }
    function function3() {
        $this->function4();
    }
    function function4() {
        echo  var_dump(self::CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

If the function belongs to another class I recommend you first store it in a variable ...:

```
class Main1{
    const CONSTANT = 'value constant';
    function function1() {
        $foo = CONSTANT;
        Main2::FunctionTest($foo);
    }
}
class Main2{
    function FunctionTest($foo = '') {
       echo  var_dump($foo);
    }
}
// I can not verify it.
```

**I hope I have helped you in your question; if you need more help or deepen your query leave me a comment.**

**Update; i see this commnet:**

> @ChristophBurschka By doing that, when you use the function you don't
>   have help for retrieve specific constant (all class consant are not
>   available for this function). When you use native PHP function, you
>   just have possibilities to use available constant and the IDE have the
>   capatibilities to find them (and it list it to you automatically when
>   you start to fill the corresponding argument)? Thanks for your answer
>   about Type hint :-)

if the problem is around the scope of your `const`:

You can declare global constants in your applications (out of all classes and functions):

```
<?php
if (!defined('DB_PASS')) {
    define('DB_PASS', 'yourpassword');
}
```

It will be available in any class and function of the whole application. and its use is not to be feared, since they are IMMUTABLE CONSTANTS.

**Update recovery and implementation**

With the last way I explain, you can then make a comparison and define which data you want to use; if the data of the constant or the data sent by the user; but all this must be tied to an analysis of the user's data in a specific function that you define.

**Last Update**

With the new define you can this:

```
<?php
//declaration:
if (!defined('PASS_SIS')) {
    define('PASS_SIS', array(
            'PASSWORD_DEFAULT' => 1,
            'PASSWORD_BCRYPT' => 2,
            'PASSWORD_ARGON2I' => 3,
            'PASSWORD_ARGON2ID' => 4,
    ));
}

//call Function
$instanceOfMyClass->myFunction('er');

//function 
function myFunction('er'){
    echo var_dump(PASS_SIS);
    //Access to data:
    echo PASS_SIS['PASSWORD_DEFAULT'];


}
```